# Number of Posts Syndicated By Individual Feeds

Tags: php, wordpress

Can anyone please suggest me any solution of counting number of posts syndicated by individual feeds?

I want any plugin or even feedwordpress addon that can show stats of daily activity and posts syndicated by all feeds individually.

I've tried different wordpress stats plugins. I've even used the following code to count the daily stats including syndicated posts by feedwordpress plugin was this code was only able to count directly posted stories:

Can anyone please suggest a suitable solution for this issue?

Thanks

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$posts = get_posts('post_type=videos&category=4');

$count = count($posts);

echo $count;